# Error when trying to make cluster using R (Rscript execution error: No such file or directory)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, ubuntu-18.04, rscript

Hello and thank you for your time.
I get the error:

> cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
>   Rscript execution error: No such file or directory

whenever I try to make a cluster using the package "parallel". Other commands such as detectCores() work, but makeCluster()
 fails. I have reinstalled R and Rstudio, and I do not think the problem is with the installation.

R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
If I run Rscript in the terminal, I get a similar error, but if I use sudo Rscript the error goes away.  For example: **Rscript helloworld.r** gives me the error **Rscript execution error: No such file or directory**, but **sudo Rscript helloworld.r** works. (helloworld.r is an R script that prints hello world.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect you have something funny going on in your shell startup script, e.g. `~/.bashrc`.  Try troubleshooting with `cl <- future::makeClusterPSOCK(2, verbose = TRUE)`.  It works very similar to `parallel::makeCluster()` but gives more detailed output.  The returned cluster is also 100% compatible with what parallel returns.

Comment: I would also try in a plain R session, e.g. `R` in the terminal.  That way you can rule out RStudio.

Comment: I did try R in the terminal, and not using RStudio, and the error is persistent. I have updated the question. I noted Rscript works as a "sudo" command, and I am not sure why it is the case and how I can fix it.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, it has nothing todo with the parallel package, and the problem is that you cannot run a simple `Rscript helloworld.r` without using `sudo`?  If so, wow, you got some that messes with your R setup.  Does `Rscript --version` work?  What about `Rscript -e 1+2`?  Try also `Rscript --vanilla helloworld.r`.

Comment: You got me Right! and it is messed up! I do not know how the problem has got there, as it stopped working by sudden. I have been reinstalling everything!!    
*Rscript --version* 
**R scripting front-end version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)**   but the rest of the commands do not work!

Comment: If `Rscript --vanilla -e 1+2` does not work, then I expect `R --vanilla -e 1+2` to also fail. Correct?  If so, then I don't see how anything works in R for you, i.e. starting `R` should also fail.

Comment: R --vanilla -e 1+2 works, but Rscript --vanilla -e 1+2 does not work.

Comment: Hmm... what does `which R` and `which Rscript` give?  It sounds like they're _not_ of the same build.

Comment: /usr/bin/R     
/usr/bin/Rscript

Comment: Hmm... it looks like your R installation is broken.  Maybe there's some antivirus software causing conflicts. FWIW, here's what those files look like on my Ubuntu 18.04 R 3.6.2 installation: `ls -l "$(which Rscript)"` => `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14344 Dec 13 08:46 /usr/bin/Rscript`, and `ls -l "$(which R)"` => `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8812 Dec 13 08:46 /usr/bin/R`.  I don't think there's nothing more I can do to help you.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. This is what I get from the command you used: **-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14344 Dec 13 11:46 /usr/bin/Rscript** and **-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8812 Dec 13 11:46 /usr/bin/R**

Comment: @NewLearner were you able to find a solution? I have the same problem, fresh install did not solve it. Very strange to see that sudo somehow circumvents the issue. My problem arose when I upgraded to Linux 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

I use R with version 3.6.1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c5w4.png)

Try to downgrade the r version

Comment: It is very unlikely that this problem is specific to R 3.6.2, so I doubt downgrading will solve it.  It's possible that a re-installation will though.